# Why did Jesus come?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, life-of-jesus, historical-jesus

This is an honest question and I would just like to know why "Jesus".

"God sent his Son as Redeemer and Savior. In his Son and through him, he invites men
to become, in the Holy Spirit, his adopted children and thus heirs of his blessed life." (CCC-1)
Weren't we always his children and heirs? It does not make sense that He had to send Jesus.

This is what I found in the Gospel:

Matthew 5:17

> Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them.

But why, it does not seem like a good enough reason to be crucified for.

Luke 12:51

> Do you think that I have come to give peace on earth? No, I tell you, but rather division.

Between good and evil, God knew already who is good and who is evil. Why did he need to send Jesus to divide?

Matthew 10:34

> Do not think that I have come to bring peace to the earth. I have not come to bring peace, but a sword.

Okay, this I get to come and punish the people physically on earth, but God can do that from anywhere and have done it before. Why send Jesus to do it?

Mark 2:17

> Those who are well have no need of a physician, but those who are sick. I came not to call the righteous, but sinners.

All the prophets before him did the same thing, why send Jesus?

Luke 5:32

> I have not come to call the righteous but sinners to repentance.

All the prophets before him did the same thing, why send Jesus?

Mark 10:45

> For even the Son of Man came not to be served but to serve, and to give his life as a ransom for many.

To give His life in exchange for ours, so we might be saved. This doesn't make sense because just believing in Jesus and repenting is the same as believing in God and repenting why introduce an extra step? Why make it more complicated and divide even people more?

Luke 4:18-19

> The Spirit of the Lord is upon me, because he has anointed me to proclaim good news to the poor. He has sent me to proclaim liberty to the captives and recovering of sight to the blind, to set at liberty those who are oppressed, to proclaim the year of the Lord’s favor.

This made the most sense to me, people at that time did not understand what God wanted. God sent Jesus to explain to the people that it's not just about following rules but cultivating a relationship and that everything that you do matters. You cannot say that you are a Christian but you value money or other things more than Me. You cannot say you are Christian but there are more important things in your life than God. He sends Jesus to make the people understand what is it to believe and to be Christian. He sent Him as an example. That is what I think, and I think this scripture relates to my own thoughts. Many of the previous prophets did the same, what I don't get is why sent Jesus to do this task if John or some of the other prophets could have done it also.

Luke 19:10

> For the Son of Man came to seek and to save the lost.

Same thoughts as Luke 4:18-19.

John 3:17

> For God did not send his Son into the world to condemn the world, but in order that the world might be saved through him.

Same thoughts as Luke 4:18-19.

John 6:38-40

> For I have come down from heaven, not to do my own will but the will of him who sent me. And this is the will of him who sent me, that I should lose nothing of all that he has given me, but raise it up on the last day. For this is the will of my Father, that everyone who looks on the Son and believes in him should have eternal life, and I will raise him up on the last day.

I don't understand this.

John 9:39

> Jesus said, “For judgment I came into this world, that those who do not see may see, and those who see may become blind.”

Same thoughts as Luke 4:18-19.

John 10:10

> The thief comes only to steal and kill and destroy. I came that they may have life and have it abundantly.

Same thoughts as Luke 4:18-19.

John 12:46

> I have come into the world as light, so that whoever believes in me may not remain in darkness.

Same thoughts as Luke 4:18-19.

John 18:37

> Then Pilate said to him, “So you are a king?” Jesus answered, “You say that I am a king. For this purpose I was born and for this purpose I have come into the world—to bear witness to the truth. Everyone who is of the truth listens to my voice.”

I don't understand.

Comment: @Emu > "Between good and evil, God knew already who is good and who is evil. Why did he need to send Jesus to divide?" < Well, God knew, but we, humans, didn't. Perhaps that was Jesus' mission -- to help us open our eyes, so we could see it for ourselves.

Comment: The first question sounds like a serious question, The remainder sounds like an argument why Jesus did not need to come.

Comment: **In a nutshell** Along with all the "teaching" and "example" reasons for Christ's incarnation, Christ came "to save" people from God's wrath against sin(ners). And **only** a *sinless sacrificial Lamb* was allowed to do that.  Only Jesus fit this requirement; none of His disciples were sinless, so they couldn't do that. Earth is so glad "He came."

Answer (score 12):

You have left out what the angel told Joseph;

"He will save his people from their sins" (Matthew ch1 v21). In other words, reversing the alienation of God and man described in Genesis ch3.

The reason why only Jesus could do this is summed up in the rest of the message; "That which is conceived in her is of the Holy Spirit... his name shall be called Emmanuel, which means 'God with us'". Though people have taken whole books to explain the connection properly.

Everything else you have mentioned, from teaching to preserving people from judgment, is an aspect of that project.

Comment: John 3:16, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Stephen, I was thinking the same. But God forgave sins even before Jesus. Why does he need Jesus to come here to earth to forgive sins? Whatever Jesus did, God has done before, why send Him?

“In accordance with your great love, forgive the sin of these people, just as you have pardoned them from the time they left Egypt until now." The LORD replied, "I have forgiven them, as you asked. Nevertheless, as surely as I live and as surely as the glory of the LORD fills the whole earth.” - Numbers 14:19-21

Comment: Maverick, what was inefficient or wrong in the way God handled everything before Jesus, that he had to send Jesus to fix? Before Jesus if you just believed in God and follow his commandments everything would be right, why add the extra step? What problem is this solving?

Comment: @Emu O.T. forgiveness is like O.T. sacrifice for sin (see Hebrews ch10 v2) in that the effect is temporary. The sin keeps coming back. Jesus came to offer the permanent solution. It could also be argued that the Atonement through Christ made the earlier acts of forgiveness possible, retrospectively.

Comment: Are you saying O.T. forgiveness should be done repeatedly for the same sin? Or are you saying that N.T. forgiveness is done once at Jesus's crucifixion for all sins and applies always as long as you believe? 

I am sorry I know it sounds childish, but I just want to understand the Catholic religion a bit better, and getting real answers is a bit more interesting.

Comment: @Emu I'm sorry, I did not spot that you were specifying Catholicism, though I don't know that Catholicism would quarrel with my argument. My point was simply that under the Old Testament dispensation men were never able to shake free from sin. The important point, I think, is the relationship between God and man. It was broken at Eden and restored by Jesus as the only one who could have done it.

Comment: Christianity as a whole, so your input is appreciated. My misunderstanding is that I don't see that Jesus is needed in any of this as God has forgiven sins multiple times before Jesus without sacrifice. Why send your son (Yourself)?

The Israelite People (over and over and over again – See Old Testament)
King David (2 Samuel 12)
King Ahab (1 Kings 21)
King Hezekiah (2 Chronicles 32:24-27)
King Manasseh (2 Chronicles 33:1-20)
The Assyrians of Nineveh (Jonah 3-4)
King Nebuchadnezzar (Daniel 4:28-34)

https://onechristianlife.com/did-god-forgive-people-before-jesus/

Comment: The CCC states that "the Word became flesh to make us 'partakers of the divine nature'" (CCC 460) and that "by his incarnation, he, the Son of God, has in a certain way united himself with each man" (CCC 521). Through His human life, death, and resurrection, Jesus made it possible for us to share in 'His divine life' and be 'reconciled to God'. In other words to connect.

Comment: @Emu Yes, the relationship is the key. As God, the incarnate Son is related to the Father; as man, he is related to us. and so through him we have a restored relationship with the Father. That's "permanent" forgiveness.

Answer (score 6):

Q: Weren't we always his children and heirs?

A: **No**. Unless you are born from above, you are not a child of God, merely one of his creations.

> 12 But to all who did receive him, who believed in his name, he gave
> the right to become children of God, 13 who were born, not of blood
> nor of the will of the flesh nor of the will of man, but of God. (John
> 1:12-13)

Q: But why, it does not seem like a good enough reason to be crucified for.

A: **Necessity**. Jesus asked his omniscient and omnipotent Father if there was another way besides dying on the cross to accomplish the salvation of mankind. Had the answer been, "Yes!", Jesus would have done otherwise.

> And going a little farther he fell on his face and prayed, saying, “My
> Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass from me; nevertheless,
> not as I will, but as you will.” (Matthew 26:39)

Q: All the prophets before him did the same thing, why send Jesus?

A: Jesus told us why in one of his parables. First he sends servants (prophets), then his son (Jesus). If the people had listened to the prophets, there would have been no need to send His Son.

> **The Parable of the Wicked Tenants**
>
> 9 And he began to tell the people
> this parable: “A man planted a vineyard and let it out to tenants and
> went into another country for a long while. 10 When the time came, he
> sent a servant to the tenants, so that they would give him some of
> the fruit of the vineyard. But the tenants beat him and sent him away
> empty-handed. 11 And he sent another servant. But they also beat and
> treated him shamefully, and sent him away empty-handed. 12 And he sent
> yet a third. This one also they wounded and cast out. 13 Then the
> owner of the vineyard said, ‘What shall I do? **I will send my beloved
> son; perhaps they will respect him.**’ 14 But when the tenants saw him,
> they said to themselves, ‘This is the heir. Let us kill him, so that
> the inheritance may be ours.’ 15 And they threw him out of the
> vineyard and killed him. What then will the owner of the vineyard do
> to them? 16 He will come and destroy those tenants and give the
> vineyard to others.” When they heard this, they said, “Surely not!” 17
> But he looked directly at them and said, “What then is this that is
> written:
>
> “‘The stone that the builders rejected
> has become the cornerstone’?
>
> 18 Everyone who falls on that stone will be broken to pieces, and when
> it falls on anyone, it will crush him.” (Luke 20:9-18)

Q: **Who**? Your remaining questions boil down to struggling to answer this question that Jesus posed:

> 18 Now it happened that as he was praying alone, the disciples were
> with him. And he asked them, “Who do the crowds say that I am?” 19 And
> they answered, “John the Baptist. But others say, Elijah, and others,
> that one of the prophets of old has risen.” 20 Then he said to them,
> “**But who do you say that I am?**” And Peter answered, “The Christ of
> God.” (Luke 9:18-20)

You will be confused if you limit Jesus to these identities:

- Wise teacher
- Righteous example
- Miraculous Healer

Jesus came not just because of his identity but to change ours. Among his most important goals was to give the Holy Spirit to us to live inside of us.

> 24 Now I rejoice in my sufferings for your sake, and in my flesh I am
> filling up what is lacking in Christ's afflictions for the sake of his
> body, that is, the church, 25 of which I became a minister according
> to the stewardship from God that was given to me for you, to make the
> word of God fully known, 26 **the mystery hidden for ages and
> generations but now revealed to his saints**. 27 To them God chose to
> make known how great among the Gentiles are the riches of the glory of
> this mystery, which is **Christ in you, the hope of glory**. 28 Him we
> proclaim, warning everyone and teaching everyone with all wisdom, that
> we may present everyone mature in Christ. 29 For this I toil,
> struggling with all his energy that he powerfully works within me. (Colossians 1:24-29)

Jesus came for many reasons:

- obedience
- to fulfill God's promises
- demonstrate perfect love (*Greater love has no one than this, that someone lay down his life for his friends.* John 15:13)
- to forgive sins (which no prophet could do)

However, to Paul, the mystery of the indwelling Holy Spirit was the greatest mystery of all.

Comment: I didn't know that even in the O.T. you were not born a child of God. 
But salvation was given to O.T. believers without Jesus. What Salvation are you referring to?
The prophets saved a lot of people not all but a lot just like Jesus.
The divine gift of the Holy Spirit was only given after Jesus's departure did his death make us worthy to obtain the Holy Spirit?
Theoretically, why did God not speak to the people through a burning bush or through the deceased prophets to obtain the same or even better results? 

Why Jesus and why die and resurrect, even in the parable the son failed.

Comment: That also brings his duality of "I did not come to condemn but to save" and " I have not come to bring peace, but a sword."

Comment: I try to keep the comments short, this has been very useful but I still fail to see the necessity of Jesus. As God could have and have before done it in different ways with great results.

Answer (score 6):

You say "I don't understand", which would be expected if you begin with a false premise. The only starting point for understanding why God sent his only-begotten Son into the world is to take his statements on the matter as gospel truth. His statements are recorded in the Bible, but taking one verse here, and another verse there (in isolation from their context) will only add to any initial confusion. Disparate matters are listed in various Bible quotes, so all my answer does is get you to a correct starting point.

That is the fact that God is holy, righteous and just, but we are unholy, unrighteous and unjust. Our sins have separated us from our Creator (Isaiah 59:2). He cannot look upon sin (Hebrews 1:13) and we are all sinners (Romans 5:12). "Without holiness, no-one will see the Lord" (Hebrews 12:14). Nobody can 'work their way up' to God. God chose to come down to us, in the Incarnation, to reconcile us to himself.

It was the only-begotten Son of God who came down to us, to bear the punishment for sin that we deserve, so that God's righteous judgment of sin could be carried out - then those having faith in God's provision of grace could be reconciled. All the Old Testament saints were people of faith, so that even before the Lamb of God appeared on earth to take away the sin of the world, the same requirement of faith was seen in them, and God was pleased to call them his friends. Just read Hebrews chapter 11. In fact, as I've already referred you to it, read the entire book.

On the point of Jesus being the only way to be reconciled to God, read Romans 5:10; 2 Corinthians 5:20; Ephesians 2:16; Colossians 1:20. **That is why the Father sent the Son from heaven - as both the eternal and sinless Son, only he could reconcile us to God** - if we have faith in him alone for our salvation from sin.

Answer (score 4):

The question quotes a variety of scriptures and the question stands at a distance to assess a historic event.

Jesus of Nazareth was born of Mary, indeed. Whom is he and why did he come ?

---

One was promised from the dawn of time, a 'seed' of woman (but not of man). A 'seed' who would bruise the head of the serpent (thus, from above, a humanity higher than the serpent).

But the first humanity had failed ; cast out of the garden of the Lord, where the Lord walked, yet the Lord was 'present' in the household of a now-penitent Adam.

Thence history progressed : a Flood, Babel, Egypt - yet within all of it a people were conspicuous by their worship and by their looking for that which was yet to come.

*The question of 'why did he come ?' is intimately bound with the question 'why did they look for him ?'*

And - why did others not look for him ?

No need. No urgency. No desires. No pangs. No heartbreak. No sorrows.

But when he came, he said 'blessed are the poor in spirit; blessed are they that mourn; blessed are they that hunger and thirst after . . . . .  righteousness.'

The serpentine Spirit in the garden urged humanity to work out their own righteousness by means of a 'tree' - branched knowledge ; trunk, then branches, then twigs covering every event, all circumstances, every relationship. But righteousness  dependent on the will, the strength, the consistency, the fervour and the zeal of . . . .  flesh and blood.

But a people on earth confessed that they were not up to the task. They realised there must be another way, for they failed - always. O wretched man that I am ! they cried out.

And looked for Another Man, another humanity. Another 'seed' to surmount the impossible difficulties of living - *righteously.*

---

This is why he came.

'I came not to call the righteous (they have no need);

I came to call sinners unto repentance'.

[Matthew 9:13 and Mark :17 and Luke 5:32 ; KJV]

---

Israel wasn't looking for him. Some even said out loud 'Come let us kill him' for they wanted the territory, the buildings, the treasures, the privileges, the prestige, the comfort, the luxury.

But not Him.

Unlike the wise from the east who journeyed *for two whole years* just to get a glimpse of a baby in a manger.

And having found him, *they fell down and worshipped him.*

And then went home, carefully travelling another way lest they be murdered for their faith.

Amen.

Answer (score 1):

In God's omniscient economy (He foreknows everything) it is said that the Lamb (Jesus) was slain from the foundation of the world (Rev. 13:8) and it is also said that those who belong to Christ were chosen in Him from before the foundation of the world (Eph. 1:4).

Before the foundation of the world chosen in the One slain from the foundation of the world.

The bible says that Jesus came into this world at just the right time.  So Jesus' coming was the real time actualization of something God always knew would be necessary; even before He created anything.  If the Lamb had not come to be slain then the choosing would have been in vain.  The Law, the prophets, and all the sacrifices were pictures of the totality of it all and foreshadowed what was to come.

Faith in the operation of God, whether in response to Old Testament revelation or New has always been what has saved, therefore faith in God through the word of a prophet was ultimately faith in what God would do through Jesus and, if Jesus hadn't actually come then that faith would be empty.

God had to send Jesus because Jesus, the Christ, the Lamb of God has always been the object of faith in the salvation of God.

> Your father Abraham rejoiced to see my day: and he saw it, and was glad. Then said the Jews unto him, Thou art not yet fifty years old, and hast thou seen Abraham? Jesus said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, Before Abraham was, I am. - John 8:56-58

Think about how much God loves the world (and you) by sacrificing His Son (He knew He would have to) commensurate with creating a world that He knew would fall into shadow and need of salvation.

Comment: Up-voted +1. But I have to mention that the lamb was slain _from_ (_apo_) the foundation of the world (Rev 13:8). Not before its creation. The saints were _chosen_ in Christ _before_ the foundation of the world (Ephesians 1:4.)

Comment: @NigelJ Thank you for the correction.

Comment: You're welcome, brother. It's a common mis-quotation, mixing the two expressions.

Answer (score 0):

**Why did Jesus come?**

As in the words of the Nicene Creed:

> For us men and for our salvation He came down from heaven. - [Nicene Creed](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/courses/43801/creeds.pdf)

As the universal Saviour of mankind, Christ is the only Saviour. Peter affirms this clearly: ***"There is salvation in no one else, for there is no other name under heaven given among men by which we must be saved"*** (Acts 4:12).

Several Scriptural passages show us that Jesus was sent by the Father for the salvation of the world.

> Since all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God, they arejustified by his grace as a gift, through the redemption which is in Christ Jesus. (Rom 3:24)

> He will save his people from their sins.(Matthew 1:21)

> For there is one God, and there is one mediator between God and men, the man Christ Jesus, who gave himself as a ransom for all. (1 Tm 2: 56)

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life. (John 3:16)

More can be gleaned from reading The Holy See’s document: [Jesus sent by the Father for the salvation of the world](https://www.vatican.va/jubilee_2000/magazine/documents/ju_mag_01041998_p-24_en.html).

Answer (score -6):

**Why did Jesus come?**

The answer cannot be found in the bible, if we want the primary reason why God send Jesus.

The true answer or the Truth can be found if we seek the gift of Wisdom first, because the Spirit of Wisdom, only the Spirit of Wisdom was present with God before creation time begins.

Here is Wisdom, a daughter and companion, that grows into a Lady or a perfect Spouse, and a Mother.

> “The Lord [a]created me at the beginning of His way,
> Before His works [b]of old.

> 23 From eternity I was [c]established,
> From the beginning, from the earliest times of the earth.

> 24 When there were no ocean depths, I was born,
> When there were no springs abounding with water.

> 25 Before the mountains were settled,
> Before the hills, I was born;

> 26 While He had not yet made the earth and the [d]fields,
> Nor the first dust of the world.

> 27 When He established the heavens, I was there;
> When He inscribed a circle on the face of the deep,

> 28 When He made firm the skies above,
> When the springs of the deep became [e]fixed,

> 29 When He set a boundary for the sea
> So that the water would not violate His [f]command,
> When He marked out the foundations of the earth;

> 30 Then I was beside Him, as a master workman;
> And I was His delight daily,
> [g]Rejoicing always before Him,

> 31 [h]Rejoicing in the world, His earth,
> And having my delight in the sons of mankind.

As we can see, one need Wisdom to grasp what really happened in eternity, I mean what moved God to create the beginning, the heaven and the earth, and the only one who can provide us with the true answer is not the bible, but the Spirit of Created Wisdom.

And we can see from the succeeding verse, the Spirit of Created Wisdom, implore us to listen to Her.

> 32 “Now then, sons, listen to me,
> For blessed are those who keep my ways.

King Solomon, seek the gift of Wisdom, and He was surprise to realize that Wisdom is a Mother too..

> I am the mother of awe and true love of knowledge and holy hope. I was given forever to all my children, to all who have chosen the Lord (Sir. 24:18).

And in this good article, Wisdom is explain as feminine, a Mother to be exalted and embrace... just like the agonizing Jesus, giving us the most precious gift of all,

> "Behold thy Mother". -John19:27

> Get wisdom, get understanding; do not forget my words or turn away from them. Do not forsake wisdom, and she will protect you; love her, and she will watch over you. The beginning of wisdom is this: Get wisdom. Though it cost all you have,get understanding. Proverbs 4:5-7

> The writer of the Book of Proverbs personified wisdom in the feminine form saying, “Exalt her…embrace her…” At the same time, he wrote, “My father spoke to me when I was tender and the only one in the sight of my mother” (4:3). That reminds me of the way most parenting is done. Fathers give directives, while mothers massage those things into a child’s understanding.

https://www.jackhayford.org/teaching/articles/a-mother-called-wisdom/

> Mary is the Seat of Wisdom.

https://udayton.edu/imri/mary/s/seat-of-wisdom-meaning-of.php

I will make this long discourse short, by saying,....

God in eternity, envision an image of Himself, He saw Himself like a child in the arms of a Mother, and this vision, brings deepest joy to God's heart.

The God of Love, wanted to experience the love of a creature, a Daughter, a Mother and a Woman.

*God the Father desires to be love by a daughter,*

*God the Son desires to experience the love of a Mother,*

*God the Holy Spirit desires to be love by a Spouse.*

This is the desire of God, the Most Holy Trinity in eternity before creation time begins. And so, the Omniscient God design a heart, a masterpiece, a heart than can love Him in the Most Holy Trinity.

> Mary became the beloved daughter of the Abba Father,

> Mary became the beloved Mother of the Begotten Son,

> And Mary became the beloved Spouse of the Holy Spirit.

Mary is the answer to God's desires in eternity.

**Mary is God's dream in eternity.**

And to answer your question,

> "Why God send Jesus"...

**The answer is, to experience the love of a Mother in the flesh, is the primary reason, being a Redeemer is just secondary.**

God in eternity started to dream, dream to be loved by a chosen creature with an immaculate heart, and so, the answer to your question, *why God send Jesus is primarily,* *to fulfill God's dream in eternity.*

Mary is God's dream in eternity, the reason why God created the beginning, the Heavens and the earth.

More to ponder on **"Love begins with a dream"**, on this great book of Bl.Ab.Fulton Sheen, **"Mary, the Worlds First Love".**

[https://www.amazon.com/Worlds-First-Love-Fulton-Sheen/dp/0898705975](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898705975)

Comment: To start by saying "The answer cannot be found in the bible" (for the primary reason) then to quote many parts of the Bible is a contradiction in terms. Given your opening personal opinion, all the Bible quotes should be removed, leaving only other sources and the personal interpretations and opinions of others.

Comment: @Anne Did the bible, describe Mary is God's dream?

Comment: For suggesting that there was some lack within the Triune God that caused Him to 'dream' of a daughter/mother/wife -1.  For stating that Jesus coming as redeemer is a secondary reason -10,000  John 12:27 and John 18:37.   "Did the bible describe Mary is God's dream?"  NO.  Not even close and so it should be rejected outright.

Comment: @MikeBorden God in eternity does not need to create, He exist with infinite majesty and glory, why would God need to create the Beginning, the Heavens and the Earth? To send Jesus as Redeemer? This is illogical. Bl.Scotus in the Primacy of Christ already explain, if Adam & Eve had not fallen, Jesus will still come, not as a Redeemer, but as a child wanting to experience the love of a Mother. The primacy of incarnating the Logos, is because, the God of Love desires to be loved by a chosen Woman, to fulfill God's dream in eternity. Mary is God's dream in eternity, before creation time begins.